# Magento 2: How to get current language of store?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, stores, magento2.2

I'm trying to show a custom block for each store view / language.
Therefore I want to create switch statement like:

```
$lang = // Get language code or store view code here;
switch ($lang) {

    case 'en':
        // English block
        break;

    case 'nl':
        // Dutch block
        break;

    default:
        // Dutch block
        break;
}
```

How can I get this? I need it in this file `\app\design\frontend\Venustheme\floristy\Ves_Themesettings\templates\header\default.phtml`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `\Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface` or `Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver` class to get store language.

> 1. BY USING `\Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface` CLASS

**With Dependency Injection**

```
protected $_store;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface $store,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_store = $store;
    ...
}
```

Now use `getLocaleCode()` to get language:

```
$currentStore = $this->_store->getLocaleCode();

if($currentStore == 'en_US'){
    
}
```

**With objectManager**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$store = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface'); 

echo $store->getLocaleCode();
```

> 2. BY USING `Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver` CLASS

**With Dependency Injection**

```
protected $_store;

public function __construct(
    ...
    Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver $store,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_store = $store;
    ...
}
```

Now use `getLocale()` to get language:

```
$currentStore = $this->_store->getLocale();

if($currentStore == 'en_US'){
    
}
```

**With objectManager**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$store = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver'); 

echo $store->getLocale();
```

**NOTE:** You should never use `\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()` It defeats the purpose of dependency injection.

Comment: I think you mean "With dependency injection"

Comment: @MilanSimek yes you are right With Factory Method means with dependency injection

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-current-store-locale-language-programmatically-in-magento-2/ You can check more details.

Answer (score 5):

You can get current locale by using below way,

> Use of Directly Objectmanager in phtml file is not perfect way for magento 2
>   standard,

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$getLocale = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver');
$haystack  = $getLocale->getLocale(); 
$lang = strstr($haystack, '_', true); 
switch ($lang) {

    case 'en':
        // English block
        break;

    case 'nl':
        // Dutch block
        break;

    default:
        // Dutch block
        break;
}
```

You can call Block file and set one function for your requirement and call those function inside phtml file.

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver $locale
    ) {
        $this->locale = $locale;
    }
```

call inside phtml file,

```
$currentCode = $this->locale->getLocale();
$langCode = strstr($currentCode, '_', true);
if($langCode == 'en_US'){

}
```