# How to get the name of current localecode?

Tags: magento2, php, template

I need to get the full name (es: "English (United State)") from my store views' locale code in Magento2.

I use

```
$scopeConfig->getValue('general/locale/value', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $_store->getStoreId());
```

inside a foreach to get all store views' locale code.

I need to get the fullname(es: "English (United State)") and NOT the LocaleCode (en_US)

Comment: Check this answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/189459/35758

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Locale\Deployed\Options
 */
protected $localeOptions;

/**
 * @var string
 */
protected $localeName;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver
 */
protected $localeResolver;

/**
 * Location constructor.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver $localeResolver
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Locale\Deployed\Options $localeOptions
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver $localeResolver,
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\Deployed\Options $localeOptions
) {
    $this->localeResolver = $localeResolver;
    $this->localeOptions = $localeOptions;
    $this->localeName = $this->findLocaleName();
}

/**
 * Find locale name by its code
 * 
 * @return mixed
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function findLocaleName()
{
    $locale = $this->localeResolver->getLocale();
    $availableLocales = $this->localeOptions->getTranslatedOptionLocales();
    foreach ($availableLocales as $candidate) {
        if (!empty($candidate['value']) && $candidate['value'] == $locale) {
            if (empty($candidate['label'])) {
                throw new \Exception(__('Empty locale label'));
            }
            return $candidate['label'];
        }
    }

    throw new \Exception(__('Locale %1 was not found', $locale));
}
```

It will return the locale name, like *Afrikaans (Suid-Afrika) / Afrikaans (South Africa)* for the *af_ZA*. Keep in mind, that locale name returns for the currently active locale for current store. If you wish to make different logic - fell free to update this code by yourself, or drop few lines with a clarification for me here and I'll try to help you in changing this code to suit your needs.

Comment: TY. it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Please try this you will get current localae code of the site,

```
<?php
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $store,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_store = $store;
    ...
}

public function getStoreLocale()
{
    return $this->_store->getStore()->getName(); 

}
?>
```

Comment: I need the full name, not the Locale code

Comment: @Gohan89 please see my updated answer